# Как загрузить картинку на сервер POS, multipart/form-data(android)

Tags: java, android, post, изображения, url

Я пытаюсь загрузить картинку на сервер используя POST c помощью **multipart/form-data**. Для меня это оказалось сложнее чем я думал. Вот пример того что мне нужно отправить с приложения

```
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="imageName.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

Ниже я попытался осуществить это, но сервер мне отдает ошибку при использование этого кода:

```
public static String executeHttpLoadImage(String url, String nameValueF, String paramValueF, String nameValueS, String paramValueS,
                                                String filePath, String fileName) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = createHttpClient();

            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(); //post
            request.setURI(new URI(url));

            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"); //set header
            request.setHeader(nameValueF, paramValueF);               //set header
            request.setHeader(nameValueS, paramValueS);               //set header

            //set multipart
            MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();        //multipart
            File file = new File(filePath);                          //file path
            ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");   //body
            mpEntity.addPart(fileName, cbFile);                      //add

            request.setEntity(mpEntity);
            //set multipart

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пользуйтесь *retrofit*
для *rest*-запросов

ваш метод выглядел бы примерно так:

```
@Multipart
@POST(APIConstants.SEND_IMAGE)
void sendImage(
        @Part(Constants.IMAGE)TypedFile file,
        @Part(Constants.PARAM1)String param1,
        @Part(Constants.PARAM2)String param2,
        Callback<ResponceModel> callback );


RetrofitAdapter.getInterface().sendImage(
  new TypedFile(
    Constants.MULTIPART_FILE, new File(filePath)
  ), param1, param2, mCallback
)
```